# Camera using phonegap

Tags: iphone, camera, cordova

I have a small query.
If i use the camera api of phomnegap, it brings up the complete camera screen on the app.
Is their a way by which we can use some part of the camera screen for our logo or insert some text.

Answer (score 1):

You can't with the built in camera API.  I don't think it would really be expected, either.

Answer (score 0):

Not using stock PhoneGap.  You would instead need to use some native iOS AV APIs from Objective C.